# Is sentinel linear search better than normal linear search?

Tags: algorithm, search

In traditional linear search,
there are n comparison for comparing with the required number
and n+1 for looping condition, sums up to make 2n+1 comparisons.
But, if we follow the following procedure, we can get our answer in n+2 comparisons at max.

```
def sentinelSearch(ar,n,l):
# ar : array
# n : item to be searched
# l : size of array
last = ar[l-1] # saving last element in other variable
ar[l-1] = n # assigning last element as required
i = 0
while ar[i]!=n:
    i+=1
ar[l-1] = last
if (i<l-1) or n==ar[l-1]:
    print('Item found at',i)
else:
    print('Item not Found')
```

Although, worst case time complexity of both algorithm is O(n). Just number of comparisons are reduced, does this make this 'sentinel linear search' better algorithm for searching over unsorted array or not?

Comment: Yes but it's not always possible to have a sentinel there so it's not a universally applicable algorithm.

Comment: can you suggest me such cases?

Comment: Boring practical reasons. Modifying a shared array in a multithreaded context this way not safe. Or the array might be actually read-only for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to benchmark it. 
But there are multiple factors, which can influence the result like:

- Branch prediction. Checking some conditions is less expensive than others.
- Compiler optimizations. Lots of time the loop over array gets unrolled and you actually do less than n comparisons for looping condition.

Also as people mentioned in comments, your algorithm has to mutate the array (usually not good) and you have to keep special value for sentinel (not always possible). So the real benefit of the optimization would be really negligible.